# void error message in c

Tags: c, variables, message, void, undefined-behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>

void simpleInterest (double Princ, double Rate, int Time)
{
      double value;
      value = Princ*Rate*Time;
      return value;
}

int main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
      printf("the value is %d", simpleInterest (100,0.01,5))
}
```

I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code, i'm really new to c just started today actually, i get an error code saying:

> simpleInterest: warning return with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]

what does that actually mean ? what is actually wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void simpleInterest (double Princ, double Rate, int Time)
    {
          double value;
          value = Princ*Rate*Time;
          return value; //void function should not return anything
    }
```

You need to declare and define your  function with double return type.

```
 double simpleInterest (double Princ, double Rate, int Time)
    {
          double value;
          value = Princ*Rate*Time;
          return value; 
    }
```

When you return double you should use `%f` format specifier in printf statement.Other wise it invokes undefined behavior.

```
printf("the value is %f", simpleInterest (100,0.01,5))
```

Comment: The `printf` format specifier has to be changed to `%f` otherwise this change will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes noticed that one. leave it to OP.

Comment: You need to note that in your answer otherwise your answer is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

A function with return type `void` returns nothing.

```
void simpleInterest (double Princ, double Rate, int Time)  
  ^
  |
Return type void
```

and you are returning a `double` type `value`.
To return a `double` type your function should look like

```
double simpleInterest (double Princ, double Rate, int Time) 
{ 

        double value;
        value = Princ*Rate*Time;
        return value;
}
```

Thanks to [Shafik yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708801/shafik-yaghmour) to pointing it out that, do not forget to change the `printf`'s format specifier in `main` to `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

You define `simpleInterest` to return *void* but attempt to return a *double* here:

```
return value;
```

if you want to return a *double* from this function then you should change the signature as follows:

```
double simpleInterest (double Princ, double Rate, int Time)
^^^^^^
```

this is also undefined behavior if we see the C99 draft standard section `6.8.6.4` *The return statement* says(*emphasis mine*):

> **A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is void**. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is void.

Assuming that you really wanted to return *double* your `printf` format specifier needs to be changed from `%d` to `%f` otherwise this would also invoke undefined behavior:

```
printf("the value is %f", simpleInterest (100,0.01,5)) ;
                     ^^
```